# What information about declined flags on posts can moderators see?

Tags: discussion, tags, flags, migration, declined-flags

I recently flagged a few migrated questions because they created or held open inappropriate tags.

One of these flags was declined with the message "Why not remove the tag from the question yourself?"

Well, the answer is that I can't, as editing locked questions is something only diamond moderators can do.  I've since re-flagged explaining this.

I'd like to make sure that whatever moderator performed that decline is able to know that only they have the power to solve this problem.

So, the question: when this flag is handled, can the moderator doing the handling see previous flags, and if so, can they also see who approved/declined?  It'd be awfully convenient to make sure that the right moderator is able to be tracked down by his/her colleagues.

Comment: "Why not remove the tag from the question yourself?" - that one was my bad. Moderators can edit tags on a source question even after a post has been migrated. I assumed that non-mod users could too, turns out I was wrong. When I saw the second flag from you I then went and checked with a 20k non-diamond user which confirmed this. So please accept my apologies. The problem is that diamond mods don't have a way to see the site as normal users with different levels of rep and it's not always obvious what features/links you can see - and we're human :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators can see the entire flag history of questions and answers, but not comments.

For each flag, they see who raised it (unless it's a spam or an offensive flag), who resolved it, and how it was resolved, including the reasons for declined flags.

---

With that said, there's no huge need to edit questions that were migrated away. The stubs left behind will be automatically deleted after a while and the tags used by those posts will also disappear once no posts are associated with them. One reason to avoid deleting those stubs right away is to allow for the destination site to possibly reject the migration which will unmigrate and unlock the question on the source site.

Still, if the question has been around for a while after being migrated out, you could flag it to expedite the deletion process. Beyond that, don't worry too much about them.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of times when a migrated question creates or uses a recently created tag, they tend to be horrible things that are subject to abuse by the not-yet-clueful, like "extensions" or "server" or "library."  That type of tag needs to be stomped out immediately and with prejudice.  The longer the migrated question sticks around to keep the tag open, the more work it's going to be to clean up the tag.

Comment: @Charles If it's that ill-fitting, I definitely suggest flagging the question and asking a moderator to delete the migration stub.

Comment: As it happens, my messages usually say something like "please either remove the tag or remove the question."  It seems to be about 50/50 on what the moderator decides to do.

Comment: @Charles Sounds like a good system. :)